# SQL get left join values from left table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I am working on a complex sql query. Just for explaning purpose of my issue i have reduced to the below short query:

```
 select a.column1 as field1,b.column2 as field 2,c.column3 as field3,COALESCE(SUM(d.paid_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY a.some_column),0)  as amount_paid  
   from a Inner join b on b.column3=ac.olumn2
   right join c on c.column4=b.column1 
   left join d on d.column2=a.column1 and d.column5 = a.column1
   where ...//some conditions
```

SO i am quite sure whats happening here. I am more concerned on the last left join on d table. if the d table has no records which matches `d.column5 = a.column1` then i am not getting any results.

But i am trying to write the query in such a way that if d table retuns any values with the where condition `d.column5 = a.column1` then i want to use those values or else if there are no records in d table i just want to get the records from the result of previous joins and get the records that i need.

Here with the current query the problem is as expected, if the join doesnt match the where condition its eliminating all the records. I want to have the records no matter what if the where condition satisfies or not.

I am not quite sure how to do this in one single query. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Note: @scaisEdge and @Zaynul Answer works fine. but the problem is the amount caluclation if i move the condition in line on join and clause. The am ount calculation should also be on the same condition `d.column5 = a.column1`.So i am not really sure how to overcome this :(

Sample date below:

```
field1 | field2 | field3 | ampount_paid | some_column_to_match
--------------------------------------------------------------
name   | value1 | other1 | 100          | 1
name1  | value2 | other2 | 100          | 1
name2  | value3 | other3 | 100          | 2
```

So i have just added the last columns to explain how i want the sum. I want sum the fields only if the `some_column_to_match` matches. So i am trying to get the output like:

```
field1 | field2 | field3 | amount_paid | some_column_to_match
--------------------------------------------------------------
name   | value1 | other1 | 200          | 1
name1  | value2 | other2 | 200          | 1
name2  | value3 | other3 | 100          | 2
```

So basically the calculation should be the sum of all values in `amount_paid` where `some_column_to_match` value matches. So in the above example, the first two columns should return 200 as it as 100 in each individual field for the same value.

Comment: Don't mix `left join` and `right join`.  I have never found that useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a left join then  you should not use columns of left joined table (d.column5 = a.column1) in where condition  in this way the join became an inner join
In these case add  the condition for the columns related  to the left join table at the corresponding ON clase

```
select a.column1
  ,b.column2
  ,c.column3
  ,d.column4 
from a Inner join b on b.column3=ac.olumn2 
right join c on c.column4=b.column1 
left join d on d.column2=a.column1  AND  d.column5 = a.column1
```

Comment: Thanks will try this and post the result here

Comment: Thanks this works as expected. But this results in another problem. I have updated the question accordingly. I am trying to sum the values fo some column in d table based on some condition. This is resulting incorrect values which i dont need. Sorry if its not clear please let me know i will try to correct and explain it better.

Comment: Change the answer  once you have obtained  the solution is not fair  ..  SO is not a coding service  .is a question answer  site so  .instead of change you question  ..  you should rate  my or another right answer  in proper way  and post you new question in a new separated  question  .....

Comment: Sorry i dont mean to do that. I just changed the questions as i felt like i havent explained the question properly in the first place. Thats my bad.I can revert the question and start a new thread if you think thats how it needs to be. And as said your first solution was a gem and what i am expecting from the first post. :(

Comment: @ging  thanks  ..  and   comment me the link of your new question  ..  so i can try to    eval this question too

Comment: As disccussed, created this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442937/calculating-the-sum-of-a-field-based-on-other-join-table-columns

Can you please have a look once?

Comment: please let me know if anything is unclear for you from the other thread please