# Calculating the sum of a field based on other join table columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, right-join

I am working on a SQL query like this:

```
Select 
    a.field1,
    b.field2,
    c.field3,
    c.field4,
    b.filed5,
    a.field6,
    COALESCE(SUM(d.paid_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY a.some_column), 0)  as amount_paid 
from 
    a 
inner join 
    b on a.field1 = b.field1 
right join 
    c on b.field2 = c.field3 
left join 
    d on d.filed3 = a.field1 and d.field8 = a.field3
where 
    some conditions;
```

The output of the above would be something like this:

```
field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 | field6 | amount_paid
-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------
name   | value1 | other1 | 1      | diff   |   new  | 100
name1  | value2 | other2 | 1      | diff1  |   new1 | 100
name2  | value3 | other3 | 2      | diff2  |   new2 | 100
```

I need a new column in the result which sums the `amount_paid` based on `field4` value(if they are same).

The above query is returning like below:

```
field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 | field6 | amount_paid
-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------
name   | value1 | other1 | 1      | diff   |   new  | 200
some   | value3 | other3 | 2      | diff2  |   new2 | 200
```

But the expected result is like below:

```
field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 | field6 | amount_paid
-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------
name   | value1 | other1 | 1      | diff   |   new  | 200
some   | value3 | other3 | 2      | diff2  |   new2 | 100
```

Any suggestions are helpful here please.

Comment: Your post is confusing. You mention a `field7` which is nowhere in the results. Then you show two results but there's only one query. In general it's not really helpful to understand a question if it only shows a wrong query and the wrong output of it. Please edit your question and include the `CREATE TABLE` statements of the tables along with `INSERT INTO` statements for sample data of the tables and the expected result with that sample data.

Comment: @stickybit sorry i have updated the question. field7 refers to amount_paid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just want:

```
Select . . .
       COALESCE(SUM(d.paid_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY c.field04), 0)  as amount_paid
```

Comment: Actually just saw this and i have already applied the same from different thread :) Thanks for the response :)